# Why doesn't my Emacs regular expression with ^ to match the start of a line work?

Tags: regex, emacs, dot-emacs

I am trying to set up `.emacs` so that any file which begins with the letters `makefile` sets it to makefile mode. E.g. `makefile-something` should be in makefile mode.

This doesn't work:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("^makefile" . makefile-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

But this does:

```
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("makefile" . makefile-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because there is a path component in front of the filename, try:

```
"/makefile[^/]*$"
```

see http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Auto-Major-Mode.html (bottom of page)

EDI: corrected regexp according to Sean comment

Comment: That regex will also match things like /foo/makefiles/bar.  I think you want "/makefile[^/]*$".

Comment: Fortunately I don't have anything like /foo/makefiles/bar, but thanks Sean for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

So this is only an educated guess, but I notice that other regexps in `auto-mode-alist` that want to match the beginning of the file name don't use `^`, they use `/`.  For instance:

```lisp
("/\\.?\\(?:gnokiirc\\|kde.*rc\\|mime\\.types\\|wgetrc\\)\\'" . conf-mode)
```

(from Emacs 23.2.1)  Based on that, I'm thinking maybe the regexp is applied to the *full pathname* of the file, not the basename.  So try

```lisp
(setq auto-mode-alist (cons '("/makefile" . makefile-mode) auto-mode-alist))
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just for convenience's sake, try

```
 (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. My emacs knowledge is very poor.